# ASC Visual Basic for Java

Tags: java, vb6, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I need a function on Java that do the same as [ASC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx) function on Visual Basic. I've had looking for it on internet, but I can't found the solution.

The String that I have to know the codes was created on Visual Basic. It's according to ISO 8859-1 and Microsoft Windows Latin-1 characters. The [ASC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx) function on Visual Basic knows those codes, but in Java, I can't find a function that does the same thing.

I know in Java this sentence:

```
String myString = "ÅÛ–ßÕÅÝ•ÞÃ";
int first = (int)string.chartAt(0); // "Å"- VB and Java returns: 197
int second = (int)string.chartAt(0); // "Û" - VB and Java returns: 219
int third = (int)string.chartAt(0); // "–" - VB returns: 150 and Java returns: 8211
```

The first two characters, I haven't had problem, but the third character is not a ASCII code.

How can I get same codes in VB and Java?

Comment: Do you mean charAt(0) every time? Also string -> myString? charAt(0) returns a char, which you can cast `(int)` to int

Comment: You may not be aware that your "Latin-1" string looks *suspiciously* like an UTF8 string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that ISO 8859-1 != Windows Latin-1. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

The problem is that Java encodes characters as UTF16, so casting to int will generally result in the Unicode value of the char.

To get the Latin-1 encoding of a char, first convert it to a Latin-1 encoded byte array:

```
public class Encoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Cp1252 is Windows codepage 1252
        byte[] bytes = "ÅÛ–ßÕÅÝ•ÞÃ".getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
        for (byte b: bytes) {
            System.out.println(b & 255);
        }
    }

}
```

prints:

```
197
219
150
223
213
197
221
149
222
195
```

Comment: It works fine! Thank you very much. Your explanation was excellent for understand the problem and solution.

Comment: It helps to know that VB6's `Asc()` function is a slow and obsolete feature included for backward compatibility that was replaced by `AscW()`.  The old `Asc()` first converts to ANSI too.  But the code given above in Java is not equivalent and will break down when the current codepage is something else, where VB6's `Asc()` always uses the current codepage instead of a hard-coded codepage.  I have no clue why the code above ANDs byte values with 255, it looks like cargo-culting.

Comment: @Bob77 println(byte) will output negative values for values above 127.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake.  Shows that I was not paying attention!